# iOS run loop using SKAction

Tags: ios, game-loop

are there any downsides with implementing a run loop using SKAction for simple games, for instance :-

```
let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.gameLoop()})
let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1.0))
let spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
let spawnThenDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnThenDelay)
self.runAction(spawnThenDelayForever)
```

instead of using CADisplayLink, for instance :-

```
var updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: Selector("gameLoop"))
updater.frameInterval = 1
updater.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```